# Upgrade mysql-5.1 to 5.5 crashed my server using dotdeb : /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: mysql, debian, dotdeb

On my debian I recently added the dotdeb in order to have my PHP up to date

```
deb ftp://ftp.debian.ikoula.com/debian squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src ftp://ftp.debian.ikoula.com/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://repo.varnish-cache.org/debian/ squeeze varnish-3.0
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
```

I did 15 minutes ago a

**`apt-get dist-upgrade` to update `mysql` from `5.1` to `5.5` and now i have my all my production mysql server crashed (impossible to restart) :**

Then i tried apt-get upgrade and apt-get update -f which returns :

```
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libhtml-template-perl mysql-server-core-5.1 libgd2-xpm
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
Suggested packages:
  libterm-readkey-perl
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-client-5.1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/10.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 11.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 40695 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.5 (from .../mysql-client-core-5.5_5.5.27-1~dotdeb.0_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-core-5.5_5.5.27-1~dotdeb.0_amd64.deb (--unpack):

 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mysql', which is also in package mysql-client-5.1 5.1.63-0+squeeze1
configured to not write apport reports

    dpkg-deb: subprocess paste killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-core-5.5_5.5.27-1~dotdeb.0_amd64.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Why is this happening to me ? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be helpful for us to temporarily switch your locale to en_US and then re-run those commands so you can post the english versions of them.

Comment: I've updated my question with english logs. I must add that i don't want to loose my database as it's a production server ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what it is saying is this.

It is trying to upgrade mysql-client-core-5.5 which is trying to overwrite /usr/bin/mysql but that is installed via mysql-client-5.1 package so it is bombing out.

Try to do the following

```
apt-get remove mysql-client-5.1
```

That might try to remove the server package also. Make a backup of your /etc/mysql dir just in case.

Comment: Will removing mysql-client-5.1 will deletet all my database ? (ps i've added the english log in my question)

Comment: no it will keep /var/lib/mysql untouched.. I've upgraded from 5.1 to 5.5 just fine and had to remove server.. I just kept a backup of my configs cause if it's innodb then you need the log file size and such to stay the same. It kept my config but I said that to be on the safe side.

Comment: It doesn't seem to uninstall, see what it says on pastie : http://pastie.org/private/kxugtee9g75a2u0ulfew

Comment: I've -rm the /usr/bin/mysql but I still get the error. And same for --purge option when removing mysql-client-5.1 :/

Comment: what about if you do a apt-get -f install now?

Comment: same.. "trying to overwrite /usr/bin/mysql ..." although i've deleted it.

Comment: try this  `dpkg --remove --force-all mysql-client-5.1`

Comment: Thanks it's much better, it deleted the mysql-client, and then the apt-update -f went well

Comment: great! glad it finally worked